# Elixir Imagemagick gravity offset

Tags: imagemagick, elixir

I'm sticking two images together, putting them in a frame (the template_image is the frame) with some text (a title and artists name). Doing it in Elixir.

1. Combining the images so that they are stacked one above the other works (append).
2. Compositing the image and the frame image also works.

My problem is with positioning the text on the newly composited image. I use

```
  "-gravity",
  "SouthWest", # this doesn't position bottom left
```

to position the placement of the text. However, it attaches itself to the bottom of the first image that was appended... not to the bottom of the newly composited image. It's as if it does not see the size of the new image.

How can I correctly set the position so the text appears where bottom left. Thanks.

```
[
      "#{original_file_path}[0]",
      "-resize",
      "500x500",
      "#{original_file_path2}[0]",
      "-resize",
      "500x500",
      "-append",
      "-background",
      "Black",
      "-gravity",
      "center",
      "-extent",
      size,
      template_image.path,
      "-gravity",
      "center",

      "-composite", # new image created
      "-gravity",
      "SouthWest", # this doesn't position bottom left

      "-fill",
      "white",
      "-font",
      "arial",
      "-pointsize",
      "22",
      "-annotate",
      "+10+40",
      title,

      "-fill",
      "white",
      "-font",
      "arial",
      "-pointsize",
      "12",
      "-annotate",
      "+10+20",
      artist_name,

      "-quality",
      "85",
      destination_path
    ]
  end
```

[image: image of my issue]

Comment: Try adding `+repage` immediately after `-composite`.

Comment: Perfect! That does the trick :) Thanks :)

Comment: Cool - good luck with your project! You are welcome to write it up and bag the points because I am unable to test the answer - I don't have or know `elixir`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added +repage immediately after -composite as per Mark Setchell's comment. It worked. I can't take the credit for this one - thank you Mark Setchell.

The Docs say:

> Use +repage to completely remove/reset the virtual canvas meta-data
> from the images.

So Repage appears to reset the meta-data pertaining to image size and positioning etc - so imagemagick has the correct information to perform the next operation etc.